# omnet++: Configuring logging

Tags: omnet++

I would like to use the oment++ logging facility for debug logging. For example:

```
       EV_DEBUG << " SASSim::SASSim" << endl;
```

However, I can't figure out how to set my log level and the logging file in the simulation manual. I thought omnetpp.ini would allow me to specify this. Any pointers on where to look? Thanks.

Comment: There is an API for Module so I can do this from c++ using cSimpleModule::setLogLevel(LogLevel) ; however, I cannot find a way of doing this using omnetpp.ini so I decided to define a new parameter in my Ned modules which I can use to set the LogLevel in my module when it is created. More standard solutions (if any) solicited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct from the manual (10.6.4):

https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:configuring-cmdenv

In **Cmdenv**, logging can be configured using omnetpp.ini configuration options. The configured settings remain in effect during the whole simulation run unless overridden programatically.

- `cmdenv-output-file` redirects standard output to a file
- `cmdenv-log-prefix` determines the log prefix of each line
- `<object-full-path>.cmdenv-log-level` restricts output on a
  per-component basis

i.e. you can write:

> **.phy.cmdenv-log-level = warn

to set the log level for all modules named `phy`

**Qtenv** and **Tkenv** have their own dialogs where you can set the log level interactively.

Comment: Thank you! Help is much appreciated.