# Unable to open OMNeT++ IDE

Tags: ubuntu, omnet++

I've been using OMNeT++ 5.5.1 in ubuntu 19.04. It has been working fine.
But today, surprisingly when i am typing `omnetpp`in ubuntu terminal, it is showing the following error

"An error has occurred. See the log file."

After my last use, I did not change anything in the system and still now from the terminal I can execute ini file using command. But, I cannot open the IDE.

Would anyone please help?

**Update**

A part of log file is given below

```
!SESSION 2020-12-31 13:42:43.774 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=5.5.1.190613-08ba16f914
java.version=11.0.5
java.vendor=Private Build
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2020-12-31 13:42:48.730
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-12-31 13:42:49.049
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (114).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:836)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:765)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1005)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:357)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:589)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:457)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:471)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:331)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:39)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:156)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:661)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1476)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1449)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/inet/showcases/wireless/sensornetwork/results/StatisticQXMac-gwSlotDuration=0.15,snSlotDuration=5.5#2a0.15-#0.sca' not found.
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:260)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:599)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:54)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:51)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:91)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:835)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:811)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:522)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:731)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1564)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2454)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2211)
   at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:489)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:815)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:808)
   ... 30 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/inet/showcases/wireless/sensornetwork/results/StatisticQXMac-gwSlotDuration=0.15,snSlotDuration=5.5#2a0.15-#0.sca' not found.
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:260)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:599)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:54)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:51)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:91)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:835)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:811)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:522)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:731)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1564)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2454)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2211)
   at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:489)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:815)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:808)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:765)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1005)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:357)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:589)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:457)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:471)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:331)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:39)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:156)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:661)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1476)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1449)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-12-31 13:42:49.104
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:156)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:661)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1476)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1449)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (114).
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:126)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:331)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:39)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
   ... 14 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:836)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:765)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1005)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:357)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:589)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:457)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:471)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
   ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/inet/showcases/wireless/sensornetwork/results/StatisticQXMac-gwSlotDuration=0.15,snSlotDuration=5.5#2a0.15-#0.sca' not found.
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:260)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:599)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:54)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:51)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:91)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:835)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:834)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:811)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:522)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:731)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1564)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2454)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2211)
   at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:489)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:815)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:808)
   ... 30 more
!SESSION 2020-12-31 13:43:02.840 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=5.5.1.190613-08ba16f914
java.version=11.0.5
java.vendor=Private Build
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2020-12-31 13:43:07.460
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-12-31 13:43:07.760
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (114).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:836)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:765)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1005)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:357)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:589)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:457)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:471)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:331)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:39)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
```

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: Yes, could you please provide the log file in a pastebin(if it is too large) or give a snippet of it which indicates what error has occured?

Comment: @Allan and Nazar, can you please suggest  how to see the log file? It suggested to check /home/Downloads/omnetpp-5.5.1/samples/.metadata/.log.   But under samples folder, i cannot see any file with such extension.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982187/omnet-configuring-logging#42987465

Comment: @Allan, thanks. I read that post. This one is about configuring log. Is it same as checking log file that you asked for?

Comment: I don't know.  Never used the program.  It's impossible to help you without data.

Comment: @Nazar, would you please say how to open log file?

Comment: Files with a "." behind them would be hidden so you can `cd .metadata` when you are at samples and then `gedit .log`. If you still can't find it then I would say to follow the instructions that @AllanWind gave and configure the log file to an easily available directory. Then run `omnetpp` again

Comment: @Nazar, thanks. I updated my post with the log file link. My log file is too long, so i could not include in the post. Would you please suggest a solution now?

Comment: @Allan, I  have attached the log file in the post. Would you please suggest now? Thanks

Comment: Posting a link to the log off-site is not acceptable. All relevant content needs to be here in the question itself, where it will remain available for future users when reading this question. This is a requirement for all questions here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: @Ken, I tried to paste the log in the question, but the system did not accept it saying it is crossing maximum word limit.

Comment: Then you need to trim the unnecessary portions of that file so that it fits the limits here. We don't go to another site to get the necessary information. As I said, having all relevant content here is required by the guidelines. It's not optional.

Comment: @Ken. I understand. But i have no idea which part is necessary and which part is unnecessary in the log file to fix the problem. If you suggest me which part is unnecessary, I will trim that.

Comment: I don't know what's unnecessary, because the file isn't here. :-) I'm also unfamiliar with the log file or its content. Are the lines stamped with a date? If so, remove all of them that aren't today's date. Have you read the file yourself?

Comment: @Ken, Yes, the lines are stamped with a date. I updated my post.

Comment: @11187162 I am not too familiar with java although my guess would be an issue with your java version not being compatible with your omnet. Maybe it somehow got updated and thus caused your build to break?